# C# winform to dll with parameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In VB.Net Windows Forms compiled to DLL. DLL accepts a parameter value and parameter without value DLL not called. And want same in C# win form. 
Can it be possible? then how?

```
Public Class Form1
    Public gl_Permission As New DataTable
    Public gl_FomCode As String
    Public gl_FormName As String
    Public gl_dtServer As DateTime

    Public Sub New(ByVal Permission As DataTable, ByVal FormCode As String, ByVal FormName As String, ByVal dtServer As DateTime)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        gl_Permission = Permission
        gl_FomCode = FormCode
        gl_FormName = FormName
        gl_dtServer = dtServer
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Label2.Text = gl_FomCode
        Label3.Text = gl_FormName
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you're trying to achieve here? :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you want to create an instance of the form without any parameters in the constructor? If so just add the extra constructor below and that should do the trick

```
Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Any other code you need should be placed here
End Sub
```

**Update**

Based on clarafications added by OP, the VB code above needs to be converted to C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

public partial class Form1
{
    private DataTable gl_Permission = new DataTable();
    private string gl_FomCode;
    private string gl_FormName;
    private DateTime gl_dtServer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public Form1(DataTable Permission, string FormCode, string FormName, DateTime dtServer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
       // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        gl_Permission = Permission;
        gl_FomCode = FormCode;
        gl_FormName = FormName;
        gl_dtServer = dtServer;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = gl_FomCode;
        Label3.Text = gl_FormName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a new project using c# and make changes as suggested but error message - "Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'WinFormC.Form1'; another partial declaration of this type exists "

Comment: Change the line 'public class Form1' to 'public partial class Form1'

Comment: Error shown in program.cs -- "XXX does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Comment: Ok fixed, try the updated code. Also try to read what the error says, the answer to all the errors you have posted could have been resolved easily, I don't mind helping but I wont do everything for you.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, but still we can not force your to give parameter because in the solution both public Form1 is under overloading.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to access the parameters from outside the form? e.g. are trying to call form1.gl_Permission from another form?

Comment: Calling C# winform DLL from another project with parameter value like - Dim CForm As Form = New WinFormC.Form1(gl_Permission, gl_FormName, gl_FormName, gl_dtServer)

Comment: If your VB project has a form called Form1 and your C# dll also has a Form1 then you have to call the name space of the form explicitly or else you compiler will not know that you want the form from you DLL. For example your VB code is in NameSpace1 and c# is in NameSpace2, from VB Form1 you would have to call dim form = New NameSpace2.Form1()